# Sair de um Iframe Selenium Pyhton

Tags: html, python, iframe, selenium-webdriver

Eu estou com um dificuldade... Eu tenho uma pagina para manipular com selenium, meu problema são o Iframes. Eu acesso um Iframe principal e dentro desse iframe principal tenho outros iframes para poder manipular, o meu porblema é que não consigo sair do primeiro Iframe que acesso, para poder manipular outro Iframes e o Iframe principal.

```
    #frame principal
    Iframe = self.Web_Browser.find_element_by_xpath(
        '//*[@id="ModalCommand_modal"]/div/div/div[2]/iframe')
    self.Web_Browser.switch_to.frame(Iframe)
    try:
        # button folder
        self.Web_Browser.find_element_by_xpath(
            '//*[@id="Button"]/div/div[1]/div/span/div/span[2]/a').click()
        sleep(1)
    except Exception:
        self.Web_Browser.find_element_by_xpath(
            '//*[@id="Button-M"]/div/div[1]/div/span/div/span[2]/a').click()
    #iframe Folder
    def Frame():
        Iframe_folder = self.Web_Browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="Iframe_folder"]/div/div/div[2]/iframe')
        self.Web_Browser.switch_to.frame(Iframe_folder)
        self.Web_Browser.find_element_by_id('Resultado_SearchField').send_keys('dados')
        self.Web_Browser.find_element_by_id('Resultado_SearchButton').click()
        sleep(2)
        click = self.Web_Browser.find_element_by_xpath(
            '//*[@id="Resultado_Simpl"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/a')
        print(click.is_displayed())
        try:
            ActionChains(self.Web_Browser).move_to_element(click).click(click).perform()
        except Exception as e:
            print('\tError: Nenhuma Pasta encontrada')
        self.Web_Browser.switch_to.default_content()
        sleep(1)
    Frame()

    self.Web_Browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="Button"]/div/div[2]/div/span/div/span[2]/a').click()
    print(elemento.is_displayed())
```

Eu recebo esse erro:

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: //*[@id="Button"]/div/div[2]/div/span/div/span[2]/a

Não faço ideia porque não consigo sair desse Iframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depois de fazer o que precisava no iframe, você deve retornar ao documento inicial.

Ficaria assim:

```py
self.Web_Browser.switch_to.default_content() # Linha adicionada antes da ação do click.
self.Web_Browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="Button"]/div/div[2]/div/span/div/span[2]/a').click()
```

Porém ao que parece você não quer voltar ao documento original, você quer voltar ao iframe principal, pois com o switch_to.default_content() você iria para o documento inicial, e esse botão não esta lá.

Retorne para o iframe que você quer, que ja esta declarado la em cima:

```py
self.Web_Browser.switch_to.frame(Iframe)
self.Web_Browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="Button"]/div/div[2]/div/span/div/span[2]/a').click()
```

E caso você não consiga retornar diretamente, você deve ir ao documento inicial e depois ir para o iframe principal:

```py
self.Web_Browser.switch_to.default_content()
self.Web_Browser.switch_to.frame(Iframe)
self.Web_Browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="Button"]/div/div[2]/div/span/div/span[2]/a').click()
```